# Charges on conducting shell with a conducting sphere inside it

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, electricity, electric-fields, capacitance

If I have a spherical capacitor which is composed of a conducting sphere surrounded by a conducting shell and the space between them is filled with a dielectric , I assumed that the charge on the inner sphere is $+q\space$ which means that the charge on the inner part of the shell will be $-q\space$ ,and as the outer shell is also a conductor it will have a charge on the outer shell $q_2 \space$ so the total charge on the outer shell is $q+q_2$ is this a correct assumption ?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: where should the charge q2 come from?

Comment: @trula If the surface is charged or if it's not charged $q_2=q$? or am I wrong

Comment: in your question you add q and q2, is in the beginning you had charge q2 on the outer shell after bringen the inner charged sphere in the outer would have q+q2